# All Keyboard Shortcuts stop occasionally until reboot using Gnome 3

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

Occasionally while I'm using Ubuntu Gnome all of the gnome keyboard shortcuts stop working. For example <kbd>printscreen</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> won't print screen or lock. The command <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>'arrow keys'</kbd> still works to move windows.

Looking in the `.xsession-error` log reveals nothing. And I'm not sure what log I should look in for more information on what died. 
Rebooting Ubuntu does not solve the issue.

Where can I look for more information?